# How to set color based on interval selection in Vega-lite for line mark?

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I am trying to make interval selection in Vega-lite change color to grey for not selected line segment (see in [vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289ABkasuAAJYSdZhMB3OjBNITypBHjKTOC1ajq4STHDuTACeTupItrJkJggMgjo4gqZQcsZQOlEmwsYQlCYAcmwBJvT+JfBO-o4yDOpQyXKYSEYQ5abOTR5sRlZlABQAogomABwAjACUJbb1lIoqVWigxEiCDGpoANqgKOgAgvNMaABMI0o4vso06YFoAGarEHAAvgo7aCAAQodoYmLnl2uAWU90eLzeIF2IAAIj9UABOMYAwJA26oB6CJ6vd7oAZw8bIq43EHosHYyEfPFKI6oAkgC4o4loTDqdbkqEAcThY3hhNRJJZbIhUIAEviAOx8pmoQUvAC6r3pFiQCAgW1AshVcA+TFZrnmTyS6SWIEwwRw2vQPTg6hWgnmcFkKSuUTVqE2IAAHiAFc85UpkOoANYfbLapSO51GMgm72oUB3GhwQQkilKM0Wj5sdQu1YgRXBE2J5Opo7p82WkAARwYSFkOiaOlI+aUKUE2ZNKVkVx0chNnnCCB1epg8zt6w+lxbIHHlbIvkLzyXQA)) and it keeps selecting line as whole. What can be done to achieve it?

It is working for [points](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289ABkasuAAJYSdZhMB3OjBNITypBHjKTOC1ajq4STHDuTACeTupItrJkJggMgjo4gqZQcsZQOlEmwsYQlCYAcmwBJvT+JfBO-o4yDOpQyXKYSEYQ5abOTR5sRlZlABQAogomABwAjACUJbb1lIoqVWigxEiCDGpoANqgKOgAgvNMaABMI0o4vso06YFoAGarEHAAvgo7aCAAQodoYmLnl2uAWU90eLzeIF2IAAIj9UABOMYAwJA26oB6CJ6vd7oAZw8bIq43EHosHYyEfPFKI6oAkgC4o4loTDqdbkqEAcThY3hhNRJJZbIhUIAEviAOx8pmoQUvAC6r3pFiQCAgW1AshVcA+TFZrnmTyS6SWIEwwRw2vQPTg6hWgnmcFkKSuUTVqE2IAAHiAFc85UpkOoANYfHDdWSYB1Otgusgm72oUB3GhwQQkilKM0Wj5sdQu1YgRXBE3J1Ppo6Z82WkAARwYSAjdH8NFIhaUKUEuZNKVkVx0chNnnCCB1epg8zt6w+lzbIEn1bIvmLzxXQA), so I assume it is not problem with selection.

Also line can [change color of its segments](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEzjQATjRyZ289ABkasuAAJYSdZhMB3OjBNITypBHjKTOC1ajq4STHDuTACeTupItrJkJggMgjo4gqZQcsZQOlEmwsYQlCYAcmwBJvT+JfBO-o4yDOpQyXKYSEYQ5abOTR5sRlZlABQAogomABwAjACUJbb1lIoqVWigxEiCDGpoANqgKOgAgvNMaABMI0o4vso06YFoAGarEHAAvgo7aCAAQodoYmLnl2uAWU90eLzeIF2IAAIj9UABOMYAwJA26oB6CJ6vd7oAZw8bIq43EHosHYyEfPFKI6oAkgC4o4loTDqdbkqEAcThY3hhNRJJZbIhUIAEviAOx8pmoQUvAC6r3pFiQCAgW1AshVcA+TFZrnmTyS6SWIEwwRw2vQPTg6hWgnmcFkKSuUTVqE2IAAHiAFc85UpkOoANYfbLapSO51GMgm72oUB3GhwQQkilKM0Wj5sdQu1YgRXBE2J5Opo7p82WkAARwYSFkOiaOlI+aUKUE2aLSZTHwZROB+eezyAA).